# Why is cursor disappear in Opera

Tags: opera

Cursor disappears sometimes in Opera browser.

It disapears when on hovering taxtareas, text input fields.

Now I have it disappears even WHEN IT IS NOT MOVING. It only appears during cursor movement. When it stops - it hides!

Comment: i think, this is related to flash plugins...

Comment: Probably it is. How to solve it? Flash plugin is the latest version.

Comment: it just randomly comes, and goes away. Often related to high amount of stuff being run at the same time. Get yourself Process Explorer and investigate. I never found the exact reason for it.

Comment: So you've encountered such problem too?